# Load dynamic component multiple times with different data

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-dynamic-components

I need to load a dynamic component multiple times and pass data dynamically based on some value so that it will load with runTime data.

I have tried below example
 https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-dynamically-create-a-component-in-angular

as per example we have one messageComponent that have "message" property and 
in hostComponent we are adding one template in html file like

```
<div style="text-align:center">
     <h1>
         Welcome to {{ title }}!
     </h1>
     <template #messagecontainer>
     </template>
 </div>
```

so here in the place of template tag our messageComponent will replace.

I need something like we can iterate this template multiple times and pass 
different value of "message" dynamically in messageComponent.

Comment: So you want the value of the `message` property to update in the dynamic component every time it changes **or** do you want multiple dynamic components generated with different "messages"?

Comment: i want multiple dynamic components generated with different "messages " and we can update the values of messages  on any click event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my approach:

- in your template, create a container for all the messages

```html
<ng-container #messageContainer></ng-container>
```

- add a function that will allow us to create a component and insert it into the view

```js
private createComponent (compClass) {
   const compFactory = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(compClass);

   return this.messageContainer.createComponent(compFactory);;
 }
```

- load the component multiple times, depending on the incoming data; we will also keep track of the components which have been loaded in order to be able to destroy them when **we need to load another dynamic component**.

```js
 private loadNewComponentList () {
   this.messages.forEach((msg, idx) => {
     this.destroyCompFromList(this.componentList[idx]);

     const comp = this.createComponent(componentMap[this._crtComp]);

     (comp.instance as any).message = msg;

     comp.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

     this.componentList[idx] = comp;
   });
 }
```

[Here is a StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-comp-with-diff-data?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: I tried to use `comp.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();` but it stops the loop and so other components dont get created