# Angular – Dynamically load multiple instances of the same component by submitting a form to add a new instance of a component to the display

Tags: angular, forms, angular-components, multiple-instances, angular-dynamic-components

[Question update link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73987046/angular-dynamically-adding-removing-multiple-instances-of-a-single-component).

## Problem

I’m trying to dynamically load multiple instances of the same component, with a new component being added/loaded to the screen when a user submits a form. The idea behind this is that a user can provide details on the form that is then displayed on that particular instance of that component that is created.

My initial idea was to have some sort of data structure such as an array or map for key pair values, whereby I could add a new instance of my component alongside the form data to my data structure when the user submits the form. Then angular could somehow display every instance of a component that resides in the data structure like the following image below:

[image]

It’s important to note that the form is actually its own separate component that’s in the form of modal dialog. This form dialog is opened when the green **Add Status Box** button is pressed, then the user can submit the form and (hopefully) be able to create a new instance of the status box component with the data provided from the submitted form.

However this is proving difficult, currently the way I’m achieving this in the screenshot above is by merely displaying each component individually in the **app.component.html**, which isn’t dynamic at all and has no user control:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div class='status-box-container'>
    <app-status-box></app-status-box> //component I’m trying to display
    <app-status-box></app-status-box> //component I’m trying to display
    <app-status-box></app-status-box> //component I’m trying to display
</div>
```

## Things I’ve tried

I’ve followed a few tutorials already but either the outcome of the said tutorial doesn’t quite do what I’m asking, doesn’t work at all or it’s too complicated for me to understand.

First I tried to follow [this official guide from the Angular website](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) but this only displays one component at a time and dynamically changes its content every 3 seconds rather than displaying multiple instances of one component at the same time.

Next, I tried to [follow this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-comp-with-diff-data?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) from [this existing stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57891824/load-dynamic-component-multiple-times-with-different-data), but I found this to not work and to be very complicated, most of which I didn’t understand. Although it’s quite close to what I’m trying to achieve.

Lastly, I tried to follow [this stackblitz I found](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4aus6a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html), but it’s not as dynamic as I want it to be because each instance of the component is hardcoded into different variables,  I also couldn't get it to work.

## Observations

One thing I have noticed though is that all three approaches have two parts in common. Firstly in the **app.component.html** they either use `<ng-container #messageContainer></ng-container>` or `<ng-template #messageContainer></ng-template>`. To my understanding, this is where the dynamic components would be loaded into the html template.

The second part in app.component.ts usually looks something like this:

```
@ViewChild('messageContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: true })
messageContainer: ViewContainerRef;

constructor (private cfr: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

private createComponent (compClass) 
{
  const compFactory = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(compClass);
  return this.messageContainer.createComponent(compFactory);;
}

private loadNewComponentList () 
{
  this.messages.forEach((msg, idx) => 
  {
    this.destroyCompFromList(this.componentList[idx]);
    const comp = this.createComponent(componentMap[this._crtComp]);

    (comp.instance as any).message = msg;

    comp.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

    this.componentList[idx] = comp;
  });
}
```

*This is taken from [the first tutorial I tried.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-comp-with-diff-data?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)*

Now I don’t really understand what this code does, but from looking at it, it seems as though the `ComponentFactoryResolver` would be responsible for creating multiple instances of identical components. And the `ViewContainerRef` seems to be what’s used in the html template.

This seems to be the direction I should head in but I don’t understand what these imported classes do, and I’m not even sure if this approach would be suitable for my specific requirements.

I was hoping someone could show me a simple solution to this problem, or at least adapt/simplify the tutorials to meet my specific requirements.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the right track. To briefly sum up [the official guide from Angular](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) you should create a directive to easily get the `ViewContainerRef` of an HTML element - the component will be injected as a sibling to this. Then use `ComponentFactoryResolver` to create your components when needed.

Personally would make directive the responsible for also creating the component since it allows you to easily use it with an `*ngFor` and separate all the dynamic stuff from the regular components

```js
@Directive({
    selector: '[appDynamicStatusBox]'
})
export class DynamicStatusBoxDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    @Input() config: MyData;

    componentRef: ComponentRef<StatusBoxComponent>;

    constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(StatusBoxComponent);
        this.viewContainerRef.clear();
        this.componentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory);
        this.componentRef.instance.someProperty= this.config.prop1;
        this.componentRef.instance.someOtherProperty= this.config.prop2;
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.componentRef.destroy();
    }
}
```

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let config of myConfigs; let i=index" appDynamicStatusBox [config]="config[i]"></ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's a good start, however I'm still not sure how or where I would use this Directive and <ng-container>. I put the <ng-container> with the appDynamicStatusBox directive reference inside the template of app.component.ts. But this won't do anything yet. Ideally I would like to have a function inside the app.component.ts that is called when i submit my form. But I'm not sure what I need to do in this function. Would I need to create an instance of my dynamic status box directive? I'm confused at what the next stage is in regard to what happens in app.component.ts Thanks.

Comment: You just add an item to the myConfigs array whenever you submit, then the ngFor will make a new component render

Comment: I understand that now, however i have a new problem, because the form is a seperate component, when I call it's submit method I have to pass the data to my app.component.ts then add that passed in data to the myConfig array. However the only way I can seem to add to the array is in the ngInit() method which has the undesirable effect of always loading a StatusBoxComponent when the app.component.ts is loaded. What I’d need is to be able to only add to the myConfig array when the form button is pressed but as the form is a seperate component from app.component I can’t see how this is possible.

Comment: Just sounds like basic input/output scenario where you create an event emitted in your form component and subscribe to it in the app component, or am i misunderstanding something?

Comment: It could be what you described. I'm not really sure how I'd do that though. My angular knowledge is limited. So from what you said I should create an event that triggers when my form in my form component is submitted, I then access this event in my app component and in that I can add my passed in data to the myConfigs array, thus meaning new components are only created when i submit a form in a seperate component?

Comment: You don't say? I really suggest you take on some kind of course/tutorial, because you're in way over your head if you try to do dynamic components when you barely know how components works or how Angular works for that matter

Comment: I've done basic Angular before but I've never had to deal with dynamic components, so you're quite right in saying i'm over my head with this. I tend to learn best by putting new concepts into my projects as I go along. Would this be what I'd need? https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter