# Angular - Submit form in one component to trigger action in seperate unrelated component

Tags: angular, form-submit, angular-components, angular-event-emitter, ng-submit

Prior to this question I [made this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68632552/angular-dynamically-load-multiple-instances-of-the-same-component-by-submittin). Basiclly in that, I'm trying to make it so when a form in a seperate component is submitted it creates a new instance of a component with the passed in values from the form displayed on that instance of the component. These components are created when I add data to an array in **app.component.ts**.

I do have that working now thanks to an answer, but now I'm trying to make it so that these components are created when a form in a different component is submitted.

When data from the form is added to an array in  **app.component.ts**, it creates one of these component instances, but I only want this to occur when a form is submitted via ngSubmit in a seperate component, namely **add-status-box.component.ts**.

**add-status-box.component.html:**

```
<form [formGroup]="AddStatusBoxForm" (ngSubmit)='addStatusBox()'>
```

**add-status-box.component.ts:**

```
    export class AddStatusBoxComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy 
    {
    
      message!: string;
      subscripton!: Subscription;
    
      constructor(private Form: FormBuilder, private data: StatusBoxService) { }
    
      AddStatusBoxForm = this.Form.group({
        name: ['']
      });
    
      ngOnInit(): void 
      {
        this.subscripton = this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(name => this.name = name)
      }
    
      ngOnDestroy(): void 
      {
        this.subscripton.unsubscribe();
      }

    addStatusBox()
    {
        this.data.changeMessage(this.AddStatusBoxForm.get('name')?.value);
        this.dialogRef.close();
    }
  }
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy
{

  name!: string;
  subscription!: Subscription;
  myNames: any[] = [];

  constructor(private data: StatusBoxService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void 
  {
    this.subscription = this.data.currentName.subscribe(name => this.name = name)
    this.myNames.push(this.name);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void
  {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

**status-box.service.ts**

```
export class StatusBoxService 
{
  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject('defaulty');
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();
  
  changeMessage(message: string)
  {
    this.messageSource.next(message);
  }
}
```

At the moment when I call the **addStatusBox()** attatched to the form ngSubmit in **add-status-box.component.ts**, the name field input is passed to the StatusBoxService via the changeMessage function.

Then in the **ngInit()** function in the **app.component.ts** we subscribe to the StatusBoxService and retrieve the passed in name value from the form. This is then assigned to the name property.

Finally we add that name to the myNames array, however I want this crucial step of adding an item to an array to only occur when I submit the same form in **add-status-box.component.ts**. Because as you can see at the moment I add items to this array during oninit().

I did [find this](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm), and it seems as though ngSubmit is an EventEmitter. And it looks like you can subscribe to EventEmitters. So prehaps I could subscribe to the **ngSubmit** in **app-status-box.component.ts** within the **app.component.ts** so that I only add items to the array when the ngSubmit occurs.

I'm not sure if this is correct and if it is, I'm not sure how I would implement it. I have used subscibe before when I retrieve the name value from the StatusBoxService, so maybe I could do something simular?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Couldn't you just move `this.myNames.push(this.name);` within the `subscribe` callback? This way it should get called only when `this.data.currentMessage` emits a new value (I expect that happens on form submission).

Comment: Also note that with you current code you're pushing `this.name` to the array before it's updated (`subscribe` is async).

Comment: Could you show me an example? I tried this: this.subscription = this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message, this.myConfigs.push(this.message)); but it just errors.

Comment: Also how would i rectify the async issue where this.name is passed to the array before it's updated?

Comment: `this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => { this.message = message; this.myConfigs.push(this.message); });`

Comment: That does work, but I have a problem where it always displays the 1st item in the list initially before i've submitted any of the items manally. I suspect this is because it's in ngOnInit()

Comment: Not clear what's your issue here. I don't know how you're displaying items nor how you're initializing the list. You should update the question and share more details

Comment: I'll provide a bit of context. I posted this question before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68632552/angular-dynamically-load-multiple-instances-of-the-same-component-by-submittin. Basiclly I'm trying to make it so when that form is submitted it creates a new instance of a component with the passed in values from the form displayed on that instance of the component. These components are created when I add data to that array. However the issue I have now is that before I even submit the form one of those component instances are initally displayed on the screen which isn't right.

Comment: I've also updated this question to include the StatusBoxService if that's helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid further discussion in comments I try to give you some advices in an answer, although it probably won't be exhaustive. It's hard to grasp a clear view of your current situation and your requirements (putting together a working example would be helpful).

Anyway:

(1) It's not clear to me why you're trying to use dynamic components. If your requirement is to show a component for every item in `myNames` just use `ngFor`:

```
<app-status-box *ngFor="let item in myNames"></app-status-box>
```

(2) Take the time of getting a minimal understanding of how Observables work. The fact that you're subscribing to `this.data.currentName` in `ngOnInit` doesn't mean that your callback function gets called only once, as you seem to think. That function (the function you write within `subscribe()`) will fire *every time `this.data.currentName` emits a new value*. Only the subscription is done once.

(3) You're getting an initial rendering of `<app-status-box>` before the form is submitted because of this line on `StatusBoxService`:

```
private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject('defaulty');
```

Again, take your time and read on the docs how [BehaviorSubject](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject) works. Once subscribed it will emit its current value and since your defining `'defaulty'` as initial value, that's the first value you get in your `AppComponent`, even before the form is submitted. To solve this issue you could pass `null` as initial value and add a check in your callback.

Minimal example:

```
    // status-box.service.ts
    private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject(null);
    
    // app.component.ts
    ngOnInit(): void 
      {
        this.subscription = this.data.currentName.subscribe(name => {
        if (name) {
           this.name = name;
          this.myNames.push(this.name);
        }    
    });
  }
```